# Unable to get Selected dropdown option value in the table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to get table row as json data structure and table contains normal columns as well as dropdowns as well. Getting json data all columns along with all dropdown options as well. Could you pls help me how to get only selected dropdown value insted of all options.

Expected json:  `[{ Amount: 50, Currency: "USD", Nation: "XYZ", select:2222 }]`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#idMatch").on("click", function(){
     var jsonData1 = [];
    var $headers = ["Amount","Currency","Nation","Select"];
    $("#firstTable") .find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
      var values = {}; 
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first), td:eq(4) options:selected").each(function(index) {
        values[$headers[index]] = $(this).text();
      })
      jsonData1.push(values);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <div>
        <table datatable id="firstTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
              <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
               <td><select>
                <option value="1111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="222" >2222</option>
                  <option value="3333" >3333</option>
                   <option value="4444" >4444</option>
                    <option value="5555" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>40</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>abc</td>
              <td>
               <select>
                <option value="1111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="222" >2222</option>
                  <option value="3333" >3333</option>
                   <option value="4444" >4444</option>
                    <option value="5555" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>      
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `td:not(:first)` selects all the table cells expect the first one, and then you are taking the text content of those. For the cell that contains your select field, that gets you the text of _all_ the options, whether they are selected or not, does not matter, they still make up the text content of their ancestor all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be more clear and dynamic over the headers ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#idMatch").on("click", function(){
    var headers = $('#firstTable tr:first-child th').not(':first-child').map(function () { return this.innerHTML; }).toArray();
    var details = $('.checkboxCls:checked').toArray().map(function (a) {
      var m = {}
      $(a).closest('tr').find('td').not(':first-child').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).find('select').length) m[headers[i]] = $(this).find('select').val();
        else m[headers[i]] = this.innerHTML;
      })
      return m;
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(details));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <div>
        <table datatable id="firstTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
              <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
               <td><select>
                <option value="1111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="222" >2222</option>
                  <option value="3333" >3333</option>
                   <option value="4444" >4444</option>
                    <option value="5555" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>40</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>abc</td>
              <td>
               <select>
                <option value="1111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="222" >2222</option>
                  <option value="3333" >3333</option>
                   <option value="4444" >4444</option>
                    <option value="5555" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>      
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#idMatch").on("click", function(){
     var jsonData1 = [];
    var $headers = ["Amount","Currency","Nation","Select"];
    $("#firstTable") .find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
      var values = {}; 
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first), td:eq(4) options:selected").each(function(index) {
      if($headers[index] !=="Select")
      {
        values[$headers[index]] = $(this).text();
       }
        else{
        values[$headers[index]] = $(this).find('#select').val();
        }
      });
      jsonData1.push(values);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <div>
        <table datatable id="firstTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
              <th>Amount</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
              <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>xyz</td>
               <td><select >
                 <option value="111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="111" >2222</option>
                  <option value="111" >3333</option>
                   <option value="111" >4444</option>
                    <option value="111" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
              <td>40</td>
              <td>IND</td>
              <td>abc</td>
              <td>
               <select id="select">
                <option value="111" >1111</option>
                 <option value="111" >2222</option>
                  <option value="111" >3333</option>
                   <option value="111" >4444</option>
                    <option value="111" >5555</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>      
      </div>
    </div>
```